# R: error when using mvnorm

Tags: r

I am using R and my function has following lines of code:

```
pd <- Posdef(10, ev=1:10)
spd <- Symm(pd)
mu1 <- c(1:10)
data = MASS:::mvnorm(1000,mu1,spd)
```

But I am getting the error:

```
# Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) (from func1.R@11#7) : 
#  object 'mvnorm' not found
```

Comment: are you sure you don't mean `MASS::mvrnorm` ? You don't need three colons, two will do, since `mvrnorm` is exported from `MASS` ... also, for general/future reference, you should specify what package `Posdef` and `Symm` come from (as I don't think they're part of base R, nor of `MASS` ...)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the function is `MASS::mvrnorm`, that is with an "r" between the "v" and the "n".